# Change Previously Saved Array

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Before deserialize existing *.proto* file i need to check whether the array property *(HtmlCleanerEngineProfile[])* has already satisfied condition. If not, then i should recreate the property.

And here's the problem, after *HtmlCleanerEngineProfile[]* has been recreated (inside the constructor) this new property still has same value (and length) with old property.

```
 [ProtoContract]
 public class HtmlCleanerTemplate : ModelBase
 {
    private string _templateName;
    private int _recursiveLevel = 3;

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string TemplateName
    {
        get => _templateName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _templateName, value);
    }

    [ProtoMember(2), DefaultValue(3)]
    public int RecursiveLevel
    {
        get => _recursiveLevel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _recursiveLevel, value);
    }

    // This one..
    [ProtoMember(3, OverwriteList = true)]
    public HtmlCleanerEngineProfile[] EngineProfiles { get; private set; }

    public HtmlCleanerTemplate()
    {
        var engineTypes = RetrieveEngineTypes();
        if (EngineProfiles != null && EngineProfiles.Length == engineTypes.Count) return;

        // 1. Clone existing to restore checked state
        // 2. Recreate HtmlCleanerEngineProfile[]
        var tempProfiles = EngineProfiles?.Clone() as HtmlCleanerEngineProfile[];
        EngineProfiles = new HtmlCleanerEngineProfile[engineTypes.Count];

        for (var i = 0; i < engineTypes.Count; i++)
        {
            EngineProfiles[i] = new HtmlCleanerEngineProfile
            {
                EngineName = engineTypes[i].Name,
                EngineDescription = ReflectionUtils.GetDescription(engineTypes[i]),
            };

            // Restore checked state
            if (tempProfiles != null && i < tempProfiles.Length)
            {
                // Todo: if (EngineProfiles[i].EngineName == tempEngines[i].EngineName)
                    EngineProfiles[i].EngineChecked = tempProfiles[i].EngineChecked;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IList<Type> RetrieveEngineTypes()
    {
        return ReflectionUtils
            .GetTypes("ContentManager.Core.Document.Cleaner")
            .Where(x => typeof(IHtmlCleanerEngine).IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.Name != typeof(IHtmlCleanerEngine).Name)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

And the **HtmlCleanerEnglineProfile**

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public sealed class HtmlCleanerEngineProfile
    {
        internal HtmlCleanerEngineProfile() { }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string EngineName { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string EngineDescription { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public bool EngineChecked { get; set; }
    }
```

I've trying to create a new method (same as code inside constructor) and assign **[ProtoBeforeDeserialization]** attribute. But still i got same result. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You probably want to skip the ctor completely during deserialize - `[ProtoContract(Skip constructor=true)]`. I'm afraid I'm not at a PC to look more deeply

Comment: It seems doesn't work, the property still has same length. I just want to keep  `EngineProfiles` aware from any changes made by `RetrieveEngineTypes();` Is it possible?

Comment: Fixed by adding `ProtoContract(Skip constructor=true)]` and `[ProtoAfterDeserialization]`. By the way thank you for the great library!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `[ProtoAfterDeserialization]` attribute and `[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]`.

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class HtmlCleanerTemplate : ModelBase
```

**New method**

```
[ProtoAfterDeserialization]
protected void AfterDeserialization()
{
   var engineTypes = RetrieveEngineTypes();
   if (EngineProfiles != null && EngineProfiles.Length == engineTypes.Count) return;
   .......
}
```

**Ctor..**

```
public HtmlCleanerTemplate()
{
   AfterDeserialization();
}
```